# Python Temperature class converter (K,F,C)

Tags: python, class, temperature

Here's what's I'm trying to do : I want to code a working python class that convert everything by himself just by giving it a random value.

What I want exactly is the following :

```
>>> first=Temperature()
>>> first.celsius = 60
>>> first.kelvin
333.15
>>> first.fahrenheit
140
```

And whatever the first descriptor I set-up, I want the others to convert by themselves, even if I do the following :

```
>>> first.celsius = 60
>>> first.kelvin
333.15
>>> first.celsius += 1
>>> first.kelvin
334.15
```

Here's the code I've been working on :

```
class Celsius:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 5 * (instance.fahrenheit - 32) / 9
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.fahrenheit = 32 + 9 * value / 5
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.kelvin = value + 273.15

class Temperature:
    celsius = Celsius()
    def __init__(self):
        self.fahrenheit = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.kelvin = 0
```

Some things are working, but the convert back is not working well and it makes some errors but I **really** don't know how to make this work, would appreciate some help, even if you guys give me a 20 pages documentation.

Comment: Can you make your question more precise? What exactly is it that you need an answer to right now? For example, if you can say what action you take that gets a wrong result, what that result is, and what you expect the result to be, that would make a big difference.

Comment: "it makes some errors" is not a good problem description.

Comment: Got it lads, gonna make some modifications!

Comment: Why do you have two `__init__` methods in `Temperature`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are *properties*.  Use one common internal value and set it based on the property set:

```py
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__kelvin = 273.15

    @property
    def kelvin(self):
        return self.__kelvin

    @property
    def celsius(self):
        return self.__kelvin - 273.15

    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.__kelvin - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32

    @kelvin.setter
    def kelvin(self,value):
        self.__kelvin = value

    @celsius.setter
    def celsius(self,value):
        self.__kelvin = value + 273.15

    @fahrenheit.setter
    def fahrenheit(self,value):
        self.__kelvin = (value - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Temperature(__kelvin={self.__kelvin})'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.kelvin:.2f}\N{DEGREE SIGN}K/{self.celsius:.2f}\N{DEGREE SIGN}C/{self.fahrenheit:.2f}\N{DEGREE SIGN}F'

first = Temperature()
print(first)
first.kelvin = 0
print(first)
first.fahrenheit = 212
print(first)
first.celsius = 10
print(first)
```

Output:

```
273.15°K/0.00°C/32.00°F
0.00°K/-273.15°C/-459.67°F
373.15°K/100.00°C/212.00°F
283.15°K/10.00°C/50.00°F
```

Comment: Exactly the one code I searched for, thank you so much! Gotta work even more on those properties!

Answer (score 1):

Define it so the `Temperature` class keeps track of the temperature in *one* unit (I like Kelvin, so I'm going to use that), and then use that in the getter and setter for each property.

```
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 0
    
    @property
    def celsius(self):
        return self.__value - 273.15

    @property
    def kelvin(self):
       return self.__value

    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.__value - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32

    @celsius.setter
    def celsius(self, val):
        self.__value = val + 273.15

    @kelvin.setter
    def kelvin(self, val):
        self.__value = val

    @fahrenheit.setter
    def fahrenheit(self, val):
        self.__value = ((val - 32) * 5 / 9) + 273.15
```

Now, you can set any property and when you get the others, you will get the correct value

You can use it like so:

```
t = Temperature()

t.celsius = 0
print(t.kelvin)
print(t.fahrenheit)
```

This outputs:

```
273.15
32.0
```

You could also do:

```
t.fahrenheit = 212
print(t.kelvin)
print(t.celsius)
```

which outputs:

```
373.15
100
```

The double-underscore in `self.__value` makes it a "dunder variable", and [mangles its name](https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/underscores-dunders-and-everything-nice#name-mangling) inside the interpreter so that you can't access `t.__value` directly (you'd get an `AttributeError: 'Temperature' object has no attribute '__value'` error)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But here's an issue, when I do the following : "first = Temperature(); first.kelvin = 0; first.celsius" I get an AttributeError: 'Temperature' object has no attribute 'celsius'

Comment: @Lulzsec that's weird, since it works for me, and it seems to be working for you with your accepted answer (which has the same code as mine, coincidentally)

Comment: @Lulzsec it's because I misspelled celsius as celcius. It'll work if you fix the misspelling

Comment: Huh you right, thank you so much for your time! Sad thing I can't double accept answers, I upvoted everything from you for your work!

Answer (score 1):

I would think that placing the properties directly in that class would be easier.

```
class Temp:
    _f = None
    _c = None
    _k = None
    @property
    def f(self):
        return self._f
    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c
    @property
    def k(self):
        return self._k

    #Update "assignment to c" to perform additional calculations. 
    @c.setter
    def c(self, temp):
        self._c = temp 
        self._f = 1.8 * temp + 32
    
t   = Temp()
t.c = 34
print(t.f)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But there is an issue, if I try to assign '0' to kelvin just after making my "first = Temp()", it tells me "AttributeError: can't set attribute", why that?

Comment: Oh, I didn't provide you complete working code. I simply setup the "setter" for the "c" variable only. If you want to assign to the "k" variable you would need to setup a setter for that as well. If you want the "setter" for the "c" variable to also update the "k" variable, then you need to edit that function as well. I only provide a MWE that saves to "c" and updates "f" too.

Comment: Oh k got it! Thank you for the fast answer tho!

Answer (score 1):

Another code beside the one I marked as answer that also does the exact same work :

```
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kelvin = 0
    @property
    def celsius(self):
        return self.kelvin - 273.15
    @celsius.setter
    def celsius(self, val):
        self.kelvin = val + 273.15
    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        return self.kelvin * 9/5 - 459.67
    @fahrenheit.setter
    def fahrenheit(self, val):
        self.kelvin = (val + 459.67) * 5/9
```